# Pentaho Chart option

Tags: pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am working with a Pentaho dashboard designer and in a stacked chart particular product is having more quantity and it is occupying more space when compared with the rest three products. Is there any way to make to display the chart color evenly for all the four products